# Find max simultaneous occurrences, increase variable if criteria is met

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2019

I have a task that is meant to summarize several connections coming in to a given set of ports (trunks), into timeslots and count the results. The thing is that I would like to achieve two type of counts:

- One count should count the total number of connection to a `Trunk` in the given slot (30 minutes per slot)
- Secondly I would like to find out the MAX number of connection that occurred simultaneously: such as there have been 10 connections totally however only 3 of them was connected on simultaneously. The comments in the table indicated the "count group"

Table: RAW_DATA

```sql
GatewayName StartDateTime               DisconnectDateTime      ConDur  Trunk
GW1         2021-02-24 20:01:00.0       2021-02-24 20:05:30.0   270000  T1  --1, nextRow.Start is before discon   
GW1         2021-02-24 20:04:50.0       2021-02-24 20:08:24.0   214000  T1  --2   
GW1         2021-02-24 20:05:20.6       2021-02-24 20:07:50.1   149500  T1  --3   
GW1         2021-02-24 20:15:50.0       2021-02-24 20:17:00.0   70000   T1  --0   
GW1         2021-02-24 20:20:50.0       2021-02-24 20:21:00.0   10000   T1  --1   
GW1         2021-02-24 20:20:59.0       2021-02-24 20:24:00.0   181000  T1  --2   
GW1         2021-02-24 20:23:59.0       2021-02-24 20:28:30.0   271000  T1  --3   
GW1         2021-02-24 20:26:00.0       2021-02-24 20:29:30.0   210000  T1  --4   
GW1         2021-02-24 20:27:00.0       2021-02-24 20:29:31.0   151000  T1  --5   
GW3         2021-02-24 22:46:54.2       2021-02-24 22:48:25.2   91000   T1  --0  
GW2         2021-02-24 20:41:49.0       2021-02-24 20:43:24.0   95000   T2  --0   
GW99        2021-02-24 22:47:25.1       2021-02-24 22:47:54.4   29300   T2  --0
```

**Results** so far: I am running a stored procedure that creates a tally table that I'm using to generate my timeslots.

Additionally I have created a temp table that is run before I run the timeslot sorting, the purpose of this table is to look at the next rows `StartDateTime`to see if it is before current rows `DisconnectDateTime`. This table was built as a test table to see if somehow could count and group occurrences before a zero (0) is meet to later on do a `max` to get the greatest amount of occurrences at once.  Unfortunately I weren't able to figure out this mechanics.

```sql
GatewayName StartDateTime               DisconnectDateTime      ConDur  Trunk   nrDDT                   sim
GW1         2021-02-24 20:01:00.0       2021-02-24 20:05:30.0   270000  T1      2021-02-24 20:04:50.0   1 -- count row below
GW1         2021-02-24 20:04:50.0       2021-02-24 20:08:24.0   214000  T1      2021-02-24 20:05:20.6   1 -- counted
GW1         2021-02-24 20:05:20.6       2021-02-24 20:07:50.1   149500  T1      2021-02-24 20:15:50.0   0 -- counted
GW1         2021-02-24 20:15:50.0       2021-02-24 20:17:00.0   70000   T1      2021-02-24 20:20:50.0   0 -- jump to else
GW1         2021-02-24 20:20:50.0       2021-02-24 20:21:00.0   10000   T1      2021-02-24 20:20:59.0   1
GW1         2021-02-24 20:20:59.0       2021-02-24 20:24:00.0   181000  T1      2021-02-24 20:23:59.0   1
GW1         2021-02-24 20:23:59.0       2021-02-24 20:28:30.0   271000  T1      2021-02-24 20:26:00.0   1
GW1         2021-02-24 20:26:00.0       2021-02-24 20:29:30.0   210000  T1      2021-02-24 20:27:00.0   1
GW1         2021-02-24 20:27:00.0       2021-02-24 20:29:31.0   151000  T1      2021-02-24 22:46:54.2   0
GW3         2021-02-24 22:46:54.2       2021-02-24 22:48:25.2   91000   T1      NULL                    0
GW2         2021-02-24 20:41:49.0       2021-02-24 20:43:24.0   95000   T2      2021-02-24 22:47:25.1   0
GW99        2021-02-24 22:47:25.1       2021-02-24 22:47:54.4   29300   T2      NULL                    0
```

The issue is that I would like to increase a count if my `case` is met (sim column), I have tried using both a global and a local variable however it is resetting for every row and I can't force it back to `0`if my `else` clause is entered.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE GenerateTrunkSum
   @date datetime2(7),
   @period int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @raw_data table
(
GatewayName varchar(23),
StartDateTime datetime2(7),
DisconnectDateTime datetime2(7),
ConnectionDuration int ,
Trunk varchar(10)
);

-- Creating test data
INSERT INTO @raw_data values('GW1', '2021-02-24 20:01:00.0', '2021-02-24 20:05:30.0', DATEDIFF(millisecond, '2021-02-24 20:01:00.0', '2021-02-24 20:05:30.0'), 'T1')
INSERT INTO @raw_data values('GW1', '2021-02-24 20:05:20.6', '2021-02-24 20:07:50.1', DATEDIFF(millisecond, '2021-02-24 20:05:20.6', '2021-02-24 20:07:50.1'), 'T1')
INSERT INTO @raw_data values('GW1', '2021-02-24 20:04:50.0', '2021-02-24 20:08:24.0', DATEDIFF(millisecond, '2021-02-24 20:04:50.0', '2021-02-24 20:08:24.0'), 'T1')
INSERT INTO @raw_data values('GW1', '2021-02-24 20:15:50.0', '2021-02-24 20:17:00.0', DATEDIFF(millisecond, '2021-02-24 20:15:50.0', '2021-02-24 20:17:00.0'), 'T1')
INSERT INTO @raw_data values('GW1', '2021-02-24 20:20:50.0', '2021-02-24 20:21:00.0', DATEDIFF(millisecond, '2021-02-24 20:20:50.0', '2021-02-24 20:21:00.0'), 'T1')
INSERT INTO @raw_data values('GW1', '2021-02-24 20:20:59.0', '2021-02-24 20:24:00.0', DATEDIFF(millisecond, '2021-02-24 20:20:59.0', '2021-02-24 20:24:00.0'), 'T1')
INSERT INTO @raw_data values('GW1', '2021-02-24 20:25:00.0', '2021-02-24 20:28:30.0', DATEDIFF(millisecond, '2021-02-24 20:25:00.0', '2021-02-24 20:28:30.0'), 'T1')
INSERT INTO @raw_data values('GW2', '2021-02-24 20:41:49.0 ', '2021-02-24 20:43:24.0', DATEDIFF(millisecond, '2021-02-24 20:41:49.0 ', '2021-02-24 20:43:24.0'), 'T2')
INSERT INTO @raw_data values('GW3', '2021-02-24 22:46:54.2', '2021-02-24 22:48:25.2', DATEDIFF(millisecond, '2021-02-24 22:46:54.2', '2021-02-24 22:48:25.2'), 'T1')
INSERT INTO @raw_data values('GW99', '2021-02-24 22:47:25.1', '2021-02-24 22:47:54.4', DATEDIFF(millisecond, '2021-02-24 22:47:25.1', '2021-02-24 22:47:54.4'), 'T2')


-- Variable should be increased if not null 
declare @localvar int 
set @localvar = 0
-- Store value in max if 0 is meet and current @localvar is greater then @max
declare @max int 
set @max = 0

   SELECT GatewayName, StartDateTime, DisconnectDateTime, ConnectionDuration, Trunk, LEAD(StartDateTime, 1, NULL) OVER ( PARTITION BY Trunk ORDER BY  StartDateTime ) as nrDDT,
       CASE 
           WHEN DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, LEAD(StartDateTime, 1, NULL) OVER ( PARTITION BY Trunk ORDER BY  StartDateTime ), DisconnectDateTime) >= 0 THEN @localvar + 1 -- Add if Match 1 = 1 M3 = 3 etc
           ELSE -- possible update @max and Reset @localvar = 0
       END AS sim
   INTO #Temp
   FROM @raw_data;

       select * from #Temp;
   
   -- Creat timeslotable
       with numbers(val) as 
           (select 1 union all select val + 1 from numbers where val < 48)
       select @date, nbr.val, 
           dateadd(minute, (nbr.val - 1) * 30, @date) as period_start, 
           dateadd(minute, (nbr.val    ) * 30, @date) as period_end 
       from numbers as nbr 
       order by nbr.val;

       --Enummerate
       with numbers(val) as 
           (select 1 union all select val + 1 from numbers where val < 48),
       periods as (
           select @date as [date], nbr.val, 
           dateadd(minute, (nbr.val - 1) * 30, @date) as period_start, 
           dateadd(minute, (nbr.val    ) * 30, @date) as period_end 
           from numbers as nbr)
       select pers.period_start, @period as Period, src.trunk, count(src.GatewayName) as 'all', 
           -- Case Added in update 2
           CASE
               WHEN MAX(src.sim) < 1 THEN 1 -- if max is 0 set 1, defaults to at least one active
               ELSE MAX(src.sim)
           END AS simultaneous
       --from periods as pers left  join HDO.CDR_RAW as src 
       from periods as pers inner join #Temp as src 
       on src.StartDateTime >= pers.period_start and src.StartDateTime < pers.period_end
       group by src.trunk, pers.period_start
       order by src.trunk 
END
GO

EXECUTE GenerateTrunkSum @date = '20210224', @period = 1800;
```

So my question is: Does someone know how-to get this count mechanic to work ? The reason for why I want it like this is to be able to do a `MAX`within my last select statement (see `CASE`)

```sql
--- Current output
period_start            period  trunk all   simultaneous
2021-02-24 20:00:00.0   1800    T1    9     1
2021-02-24 22:30:00.0   1800    T1    1     1
2021-02-24 20:30:00.0   1800    T2    1     1
2021-02-24 22:30:00.0   1800    T2    1     1

--- What it should be based on input
period_start            period  trunk all   simultaneous
2021-02-24 20:00:00.0   1800    T1    9     5 -- See RAW_table for clarification
2021-02-24 22:30:00.0   1800    T1    1     1
2021-02-24 20:30:00.0   1800    T2    1     1
2021-02-24 22:30:00.0   1800    T2    1     1
```

Example output

```
Trunk  Start                                Period   All  sim
T1       2021:02:24 22:30:0.0     1800      5     2
```

#### Update 1

Looking at Sørens answer I tried to `inner join` it to my 30 minute periods.
As Such
SET NOCOUNT ON
USE [dbo_CDR]
GO

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenerateTrunkSumv1]
@date datetime2(1),
@ST datetime2(1),
@DT datetime2(1),
@tn varchar(23),
@period int
AS
BEGIN

WITH TrunkGroup
AS (
    SELECT
        IngressTrunkGroup as Trunk
    ,StartDateTime
    ,DisconnectDateTime
    FROM 
        [dbo].[CDR_RAW]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        EgressTrunkGroup
    ,StartDateTime
    ,DisconnectDateTime
    FROM 
        [dbo].[CDR_RAW]
),
Times AS
(SELECT
        rd.StartDateTime tm
    ,rd.Trunk
    FROM TrunkGroup rd
    UNION
    SELECT
        rd.DisconnectDateTime
    ,rd.Trunk
    FROM TrunkGroup rd),
intervals
AS
(SELECT
        tm tm1
    ,LEAD(tm, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Trunk ORDER BY tm) tm2
    ,Trunk
    FROM Times)
SELECT
    i.Trunk
,i.tm1
,i.tm2
,COUNT(*) simultaneous
INTO #TEMP
FROM intervals i
INNER JOIN TrunkGroup rd
    ON rd.DisconnectDateTime >= i.tm1
        AND rd.StartDateTime < i.tm2
        AND i.Trunk = rd.Trunk
        AND i.tm2 IS NOT null
GROUP BY i.Trunk
        ,i.tm1
        ,i.tm2
ORDER BY i.Trunk,i.tm1

;

WITH Numbers(val) AS
(
SELECT
    1 
    
    UNION ALL
    
SELECT
    val + 1 
FROM
    numbers 
WHERE
    val < 48
)
SELECT
PeriodSummary.period_start
,PeriodSummary.period_end
,PeriodSummary.Period
,PeriodSummary.Trunk
,PeriodSummary.[all]
,PeriodSummary.simultaneous
FROM
(
    SELECT
    pers.period_start
    ,pers.period_end
    ,@period as [Period]
    ,src.Trunk
    ,src.simultaneous
    ,COUNT(*) as [all]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
        dateadd(minute, (val - 1) * 30, '20210224') as period_start
        ,dateadd(minute, (val    ) * 30, '20210224') as period_end 
        FROM
        numbers
    ) pers 
INNER JOIN
    #TEMP as src 
    ON  src.tm1 >= pers.period_start
            AND src.tm1 < pers.period_end
GROUP BY
    src.Trunk
    ,pers.period_start
    ,pers.period_end
    ,src.simultaneous
) PeriodSummary

END
GO

EXECUTE [dbo].[GenerateTrunkSumv1] @date = '20210224', @period = 1800, @ST = '2021-02-24 20:00:00.0', @DT = '2021-02-24 22:30:00.0000000', @tn = 'test';
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT as 'Inserted'
GO
```

The issue with this solution is that I'm receiving duplicated lines if a time period crosses a 30 minute mark with one of the values (start / disconnect time)

Current output

```
period_start              period_end                Period  Trunk   all     simultaneous
2021-02-24 20:00:00.0     2021-02-24 20:30:00.0     1800    I1      1       1
2021-02-24 20:00:00.0     2021-02-24 20:30:00.0     1800    I1      1       2
2021-02-24 20:30:00.0     2021-02-24 21:00:00.0     1800    I1      6       1
2021-02-24 20:30:00.0     2021-02-24 21:00:00.0     1800    I1      22      2
2021-02-24 20:30:00.0     2021-02-24 21:00:00.0     1800    I1      16      3
2021-02-24 20:30:00.0     2021-02-24 21:00:00.0     1800    I2      1       1
2021-02-24 20:30:00.0     2021-02-24 21:00:00.0     1800    I2      2       2
```

As you can see above, the first line occurs twice since it has an entry that passes through a mark.

```
--Surrounding rows causing this issue
I1  2021-02-24 20:23:43.1   2021-02-24 20:24:34.6   1
I1  2021-02-24 20:24:34.6   2021-02-24 20:31:09.5   2
I1  2021-02-24 20:31:09.5   2021-02-24 20:32:32.9   3
I1  2021-02-24 20:32:32.9   2021-02-24 20:32:42.3   3
I1  2021-02-24 20:32:42.3   2021-02-24 20:32:51.4   3
I1  2021-02-24 20:32:51.4   2021-02-24 20:33:05.1   3
```

Does anyone know a solution that moves away from the locked periods having to start at every 30 minutes (00:00 / 00:30) to just creat 30 minutes from the first timeslot.

Optionally if the second row could be changed to reflect the Start/-Disconnection time for the outliers.

Comment: I think there is still a glitch in your logic: you evaluate for each connection, if it is is within the time of the previous connection. Now imagine the following setting: you have the first connection starting at 07:00 and ending at 07:15, the second connection starting at 07:05 and ending at 07:07 (which is within the first connection) and a third connectrion starting at 07:10 and ending at 07:13 - ehich is within the first connection but not within the previous connection... in this case you wouldn't identify it as simultaneous connection, would you?

Comment: That's a really good point, one that I have overseen. I will take a look at the solution posted below witch does not focus on just one row. I will also take this comment into consideration when validating/testing this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I were to find simultaneous connection I would not look at only the next entry.

Consider you have a start and end time for each connection. Make all consecutive intervals using these times, and you will have all "interesting" intervals for you data set.
Then join those intervals with your raw data, and you can count for each interval how many connections are in it. Since you have all times where somethin happens, you are sure to catch ecerything.

First I Select all times:

```
WITH Times
AS
(SELECT
        rd.StartDateTime tm
       ,rd.Trunk
    FROM #raw_data rd
    UNION
    SELECT
        rd.DisconnectDateTime
       ,rd.Trunk
    FROM #raw_data rd)
```

This is just all of the times for you dataset - grouped by trunk, since we want to keep those apart.

Then create all intervals:

```
intervals
AS
(SELECT
        tm tm1
       ,LEAD(tm, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Trunk ORDER BY tm) tm2
       ,Trunk
    FROM Times)
```

Here we get the first time of day, to the second time of day, second time of day to third time of day etc. That is we have split the periods for all connections into the exact intervals either starting or ending with a connection start or disconnect.

Now we just need to join against the raw data to see how many connections are in each interval:

```
SELECT
    i.Trunk
   ,i.tm1
   ,i.tm2
   ,COUNT(*) simultaneous
FROM intervals i
INNER JOIN #raw_data rd
    ON rd.DisconnectDateTime >= i.tm1
        AND rd.StartDateTime < i.tm2
        AND i.Trunk = rd.Trunk
        AND i.tm2 IS NOT null
GROUP BY i.Trunk
        ,i.tm1
        ,i.tm2
ORDER BY i.trunk,i.tm1
```

This gives this table:

```
+-------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+
| Trunk |             tm1             |             tm2             | simultaneous |
+-------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+
| T1    | 2021-02-24 20:01:00.0000000 | 2021-02-24 20:04:50.0000000 |            1 |
| T1    | 2021-02-24 20:04:50.0000000 | 2021-02-24 20:05:20.6000000 |            2 |
| T1    | 2021-02-24 20:05:20.6000000 | 2021-02-24 20:05:30.0000000 |            3 |
| T1    | 2021-02-24 20:05:30.0000000 | 2021-02-24 20:07:50.1000000 |            3 |
| T1    | 2021-02-24 20:07:50.1000000 | 2021-02-24 20:08:24.0000000 |            2 |
| T1    | 2021-02-24 20:08:24.0000000 | 2021-02-24 20:15:50.0000000 |            1 |
| T1    | 2021-02-24 20:15:50.0000000 | 2021-02-24 20:17:00.0000000 |            1 |
| T1    | 2021-02-24 20:17:00.0000000 | 2021-02-24 20:20:50.0000000 |            1 |
| T1    | 2021-02-24 20:20:50.0000000 | 2021-02-24 20:20:59.0000000 |            1 |
| T1    | 2021-02-24 20:20:59.0000000 | 2021-02-24 20:21:00.0000000 |            2 |
| T1    | 2021-02-24 20:21:00.0000000 | 2021-02-24 20:24:00.0000000 |            2 |
| T1    | 2021-02-24 20:24:00.0000000 | 2021-02-24 20:25:00.0000000 |            1 |
| T1    | 2021-02-24 20:25:00.0000000 | 2021-02-24 20:28:30.0000000 |            1 |
| T1    | 2021-02-24 20:28:30.0000000 | 2021-02-24 22:46:54.2000000 |            1 |
| T1    | 2021-02-24 22:46:54.2000000 | 2021-02-24 22:48:25.2000000 |            1 |
| T2    | 2021-02-24 20:41:49.0000000 | 2021-02-24 20:43:24.0000000 |            1 |
| T2    | 2021-02-24 20:43:24.0000000 | 2021-02-24 22:47:25.1000000 |            1 |
| T2    | 2021-02-24 22:47:25.1000000 | 2021-02-24 22:47:54.4000000 |            1 |
+-------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------+
```

Now you can join that against your set periods, remembering to make the intervals openended, and you can find the max number of simultaneous connectyions in each period.

The full query is here:

```
WITH Times
AS
(SELECT
        rd.StartDateTime tm
       ,rd.Trunk
    FROM #raw_data rd
    UNION
    SELECT
        rd.DisconnectDateTime
       ,rd.Trunk
    FROM #raw_data rd),
intervals
AS
(SELECT
        tm tm1
       ,LEAD(tm, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Trunk ORDER BY tm) tm2
       ,Trunk
    FROM Times)
SELECT
    i.Trunk
   ,i.tm1
   ,i.tm2
   ,COUNT(*) simultaneous
FROM intervals i
INNER JOIN #raw_data rd
    ON rd.DisconnectDateTime >= i.tm1
        AND rd.StartDateTime < i.tm2
        AND i.Trunk = rd.Trunk
        AND i.tm2 IS NOT null
GROUP BY i.Trunk
        ,i.tm1
        ,i.tm2
ORDER BY i.trunk,i.tm1
```

Comment: Thank you for broadening this to a bigger scope than just a single row; I wasn't sure how to archive this. I Will have a look at this implementation today to ensure that I understand it fully :). You will hear from me once I'll try it out.

Comment: This work quite well and suited most of my requirements, however, it is not all the way there for me just yet, currently, the period is open-ended as you mentioned. But I have been challenged with the need to group them in chunk-sized (etc 30 minutes) to allow a reporter in SSRS to choose a time span from a dropdown (30min, 1h, 24h, etc) Do you have any pointer on this?

Comment: If I additionaly  would like to count ”all” connections for every timeslot were would you add this in, since we are union the table here i seem to get a duplicate count (On some of the values) when trying to ‘select count(*)  As all’ i’ll updated my question with an example output

Comment: Hey @søren-kongstad, I have now spent days trying to figure out how to join the output generated to match my 30-minute criteria. Unfortunately, though I haven't been able to complete it. I added an update showing the current result and the code I used to implement it. Would you have the time to expand a bit more on how to archive this?